# How do I align icons from the start of a line to the end of a line which is evenly distributed horizontally?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I have the icon display from the beginning of the line to the end of the line and and have it evenly distributed?  The icons should be evenly distributed and an icon should be at the start and end of the line.  I can't figure out how to get it to the end.

Thanks for any help!

```css
.steps {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.steps div {
    line-height: 3em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.steps .complete-step {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #95CA3E;
}

.steps .incomplete-step {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #0369B3;
}

.steps div:after {
    content: "\00a0\00a0";
}

.steps div:before {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -2.5em;
    float: none;
    line-height: 1em;
}

.steps .complete-step:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f111";
    color: #95CA3E;
    background-color: #95CA3E;
    height: 1.2em;
    width: 1.2em;
    border-radius: 1.2em;
}

.steps .incomplete-step:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f192";
    font-size: 1.5em;
    bottom: -1.6em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="steps">
    <div class="complete-step"></div>
    <div class="complete-step"></div>
    <div class="incomplete-step"></div>
    <div class="incomplete-step"></div>
    <div class="incomplete-step"></div>
    <div class="incomplete-step"></div>
    <div class="incomplete-step"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid a line at the end is easily done use the `:not()` selector, combined with `:last-child`, where all but the last child will get a line

```
.steps .complete-step:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #95CA3E;
}
```

When it comes to the line shining through, as the pseudo are a part of the items, its border will be beneath it. You can either move the pseudo outside, using e.g. a negative margin, and then resize the items so they match the space between, or simply give the incomplete pseudo a background color, as I did in below sample.

Stack snippet

```css
.steps {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.steps div {
  line-height: 3em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.steps .complete-step:not(:last-child) {       /*  changed  */
  border-bottom: 4px solid #95CA3E;
}

.steps .incomplete-step:not(:last-child) {     /*  changed  */
  border-bottom: 4px solid #0369B3;
}

.steps div:after {
  content: "\00a0\00a0";
}

.steps div:before {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -2.5em;
  float: none;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.steps .complete-step:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f111";
  color: #95CA3E;
  background-color: #95CA3E;
  height: 1.2em;
  width: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 1.2em;
}

.steps .incomplete-step:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f192";
  background-color: white;                     /*  added  */
  font-size: 1.5em;
  bottom: -1.6em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="steps">
  <div class="complete-step"></div>
  <div class="complete-step"></div>
  <div class="incomplete-step"></div>
  <div class="incomplete-step"></div>
  <div class="incomplete-step"></div>
  <div class="incomplete-step"></div>
  <div class="incomplete-step"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses!  The first and third solution work for me.  Thank you for taking the time to respond.  I am new and unable to vote up the responses.

Comment: @TerryDoll I just updated my answer, to make the lines hide beneath the icons.

Comment: @TerryDoll Note, anyone can accept an answer, by clicking the gray check mark at the left side of the chosen answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that because the flexbox computes the size of its children.
Your icons aren't the children, they are in the children (in the `:before` pseudo-element). What you can quickly do though, is to trick it and remove the line on the last child ;) Else, you'll have to review your DOM I think.

Using the `:last-child` selector, you can also hack the width of the last element or anything you'll like to improve the design on the end of the line!

```css
.steps {
            width: 100%;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: stretch;
        }

        .steps div {
            line-height: 3em;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            align-items: stretch;
        }

        .steps .complete-step {
            border-bottom: 4px solid #95CA3E;
        }

        .steps .incomplete-step {
            border-bottom: 4px solid #0369B3;
        }

        .steps .complete-step:last-child {
            border-bottom: none;
        }

        .steps .incomplete-step:last-child {
            border-bottom: none;
        }

        .steps div:after {
            content: "\00a0\00a0";
        }

        .steps div:before {
            position: relative;
            bottom: -2.5em;
            float: none;
            line-height: 1em;
        }

        .steps .complete-step:before {
            font-family: 'FontAwesome';
            content: "\f111";
            color: #95CA3E;
            background-color: #95CA3E;
            height: 1.2em;
            width: 1.2em;
            border-radius: 1.2em;
        }

        .steps .incomplete-step:before {
            font-family: 'FontAwesome';
            content: "\f192";
            font-size: 1.5em;
            bottom: -1.6em;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="steps">
        <div class="complete-step"></div>
        <div class="complete-step"></div>
        <div class="incomplete-step"></div>
        <div class="incomplete-step"></div>
        <div class="incomplete-step"></div>
        <div class="incomplete-step"></div>
        <div class="incomplete-step"></div>
    </div>
```