# How to get custom stepper like element (with custom icons) with html

Tags: html, css, angular

I would like to know how can I get something like this image with HTML and CSS. I searched a lot for similar results but could not find something useful.

I tried to adapt  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47697813/how-do-i-align-icons-from-the-start-of-a-line-to-the-end-of-a-line-which-is-even) to my needs but also did not work quite right.

What I need is to have some component like the image attached, where I can pass an array of steps (for each row) as icons to be displayed.

I'm using angular 11

[image: need to be]

Answer (score 0):

if You are using angular. You can use Angular material css framework and use `mat-horizontal-stepper`

You can edit and add icons each step. just customize the css using `ng-deep`

see documentation here:

https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Comment: Yeah, I tried already. this angular stepper is for really coupled with form usage. I need just one for displaying icons. Moreover, this angular stepper does not allow changing the icons easily